# Not able to update object from iOS on PARSE Sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios8

I have tried to update Parse object from Parse CloudCode function.  I want to update status_id for one particular entry whose objectId is "vZveFx3KcP”. Whenever i call following function no entry gets updated. but whenever i added manual entry or entry from Android device it gets updated without any issue. For iOS i am using latest Parse version "1.11.0". **I got this issue only to those entries who gets added by iOS platfrom.**

Can any one Please explain where i am going wrong. I am new to javascript programming so let me know if you need additional information from me. You can check my code below. I have tried calling cloud function from Parse API console.

```
   Parse.Cloud.define("freshFunction", function(request, response) {

               var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Booking");
               var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
               query.equalTo("objectId", "vZveFx3KcP");
               query.first({
                          success: function(results) {

                          alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + "user_id");

                          results.set("status_id", 2);
                          results.save();
                          response.success();
                          },
                          error: function(error) {
                          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                           response.error();
                          }
                          });

               });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in iOS?

Comment: I am updating these entries from cloud code. I am able to fetch and update those entries from iOS platform. But those entries are not updating when we call them from cloud code. In cloud code i am getting success  message but in reality its not at all updated. This happens to entries who are added from iOS platform. For android and manual entry function works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this problem by creating cloud function and calling it from iOS platform. Added following code in cloud.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("callCloudFunctionFromDevice", function(request, response) {

                   var bookfromtime = request.params.book_fromtime;
                   var booktotime = request.params.book_totime;
                   var bookdate = request.params.book_date;
                   var roommacid = request.params.room_mac_id;
                   var userid= request.params.user_id;
                   var ttl= request.params.title;
                   var desc= request.params.description;
                   var statusid= request.params.status_id;


                   var SensorsObject = Parse.Object.extend("Booking");
                   var senorObject = new SensorsObject();

                   senorObject.set("book_fromtime", bookfromtime);
                   senorObject.set("book_totime", booktotime);
                   senorObject.set("book_date", bookdate);
                   senorObject.set("room_mac_id", roommacid);
                   senorObject.set("user_id", userid);
                   senorObject.set("title", ttl);
                   senorObject.set("description", desc);
                   senorObject.set("status_id", statusid);




                   senorObject.save(null, {
                                    success: function(gameScore) {
                                    // response.success("Sensor Data is stored");
                                    response.success("success");
                                    },
                                    error: function(gameScore, error) {
                                    // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                                    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                                    alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
                                    response.error("Failed to store object data");
                                    }
                                    });
                   });
```

once deploying the above code on the cloud i called the 'callCloudFunctionFromDevice' function from iOS platform. Please refer following code

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"callCloudFunctionFromDevice" //This is the Parse function
                       withParameters:mDictionary
                                block:^(NSString *CalUsed1, NSError *error) { // This is where the block starts
                                    if (!error) { //if the block retrieves the data with no problem, this will run
                                        NSLog(@"Calories");
                                        [self hideBusyActivityView];
                                        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"TDEE IN FN is");
                                        [self hideBusyActivityView];
                                        [self showAlertWithMessage:error.localizedDescription];
                                    }
                                }];
```

where mDictionary is the payload.

Thanks,

Akshay Aher.